# How to validate a custom id in regex as shown below

Tags: php

I want to validate my id(s) that looks like in singe statement( using regular expression)

```
$id='S-PGA/14/012';
```

```
Where:
always value of 
- 'S' must be single character
- value of PGA must be string of length 3 to 5
- 14 is numer of exactly 2 in length
- 012 is the numer too with exactly 3 length.
```

Comment: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 
**`/^[A-Z]-[A-Z]{3,5}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{3}$/`** as [regexp](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) to validate you string. If you'd like to make case insensitive validation use **`/^[A-Z]-[A-Z]{3,5}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{3}$/i`**. Use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to validate the regexp.

The sample php code is below:

```
$id='S-PGA/14/012';
$pattern = '/^[A-Z]-[A-Z]{3,5}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{3}$/';
// Uncomment line below for case insensitive check
// $pattern = '/^[A-Z]-[A-Z]{3,5}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{3}$/i';

if (preg_match($pattern, $id)) {
    echo 'valid';
} else {
    echo 'not valid';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to test if the ID is valid:

```
function is_id_valid ( $id ) {
    $patern = '/^[A-Z]-[A-Z]{3,5}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{3}$/';

    if ( preg_match($pattern, $id) ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If the letters in the ID are not case sensitive you can append an 'i' to the regex in order to make it case insensitive.